# Validation Rule to Restrict Users from Changing Ownership (if they're the owner)

Tags: validation

I have created this validation rule to restrict users from updating account ownership if a record has a Ship to ID populated that starts with a 6 or 7 unless you have an admin or IT user profile.

We are finding that if you are the Account owner of the record, you can still the Account owner from yourself to another user (the rule does restrict from other users changing other peoples account owners). Can someone help add a restriction to ensure that if a Ship ID stars with a 6 or 7 NO ONE (even account owners) can change the owner of the Account unless you have an admin or IT user profile?

Current Validation Rule:

AND (
    LEFT (Ship_To_ID__c, 1) = "6" || LEFT (Ship_To_ID__c, 1) ="7",
    ISCHANGED ( Name ), 
  AND($Profile.Id <> "00eC00000012E4i",$Profile.Id <> "00e800000017STg")
)

Answer (score 1):

Your validation is checking whether the Name field has changed, but it sounds like you want to check whether the Account Owner field has changed. So you probably want something more like this:

```
AND( 
  LEFT (Ship_To_ID__c, 1) = "6" || LEFT (Ship_To_ID__c, 1) ="7", 
  ISCHANGED ( OwnerId ), 
  AND(
    $Profile.Id <> "00eC00000012E4i",
    $Profile.Id <> "00e800000017STg"
  )
)
```